# Include_external_msproject cmake .androidproj

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, cmake, ant

I want to use include_external_msproject to add a .androidproj ant build package but it seems this function only likes .vcxproj files. Does cmake check the file suffix or project guid to identify the type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but the answer might be relevant to those searching for include_external_msproject and androidproj. You actually CAN add androidproj with include_external_msproject, but you have to specify project TYPE, e.g.:

```
  include_external_msproject(targetName 
        Path/To/Project/project.androidproj 
        TYPE 39E2626F-3545-4960-A6E8-258AD8476CE5 
        cmakeTargetName)
```

It works, at least with CMake 3.26 + Visual Studio 2022.

It ends up slightly less useful than I'd like - since this is not a "normal" CMake target, you can't make it link a library generated by another target (this would require CMake to modify the androidproj, but it doesn't "own" it), so my goal of generating a VS project that can build an APK that depends on a native library remains unrealized for now.